# How to use file from home directory in docker compose secret?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build a docker container with private node packages in it. I have followed [this guide](https://www.alexandraulsh.com/2019/02/24/docker-build-secrets-and-npmrc/) to use secrets to reference npmrc file securely to install the dependencies. I can get this to work when building the image directly using a command like this: `docker build --secret id=npm,src=$HOME/.npmrc .` but I cannot get this working with docker compose. When running a `docker compose build` it acts like there is no npmrc file and gives me a 401 when trying to download dependencies.

I provided a stripped down version of Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml below.

**Dockerfile**

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM node:14.17.1

COPY . .

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npm,target=/root/.npmrc yarn --frozen-lockfile --production

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  example:
    build: packages/example
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    secrets:
      - npm
secrets:
  npm:
    file: ${HOME}/.npmrc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [docker-compose v2.5.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.5.0) this is now possible.

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,target=/root/mysecret cat /root/mysecret
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  my-app:
    build:
      context: .
      secrets:
        - mysecret

secrets:
  mysecret:
   file: ~/.npmrc
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that this fixed my personal issue. So eventhough this had no points for over half a year, still helped someone out!

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that my docker-compose.yml is specifying secrets for runtime of a container vs build time. Support for build secrets from docker compose has not been implemented yet. Here is the outstanding PR: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/7046.

For now, I have to build the image using `docker build ...` and reference the named image locally in docker-compose.yml instead of building through docker compose.